# Permission denied when trying to write file

Tags: php, fopen

I'm getting this error:

Warning: fopen(name.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phptests/post.php on line 5
Could not write file

I'm trying to retrieve form data and pass it into a text file like so:

```
<?php
   $name    = $_POST['name'];
   $surname = $_POST['surname'];

   $fh = fopen("name.txt", "w") or die("Could not write file");

   fwrite($fh, $name, $surname);
   fclose($fh);   
?>
```

I'm using Komodo Edit and my php files are saved in the "htdocs" folder provided by XAMPP.

Can anyone tell me why I'm not able to write the file?

Answer (score 2):

As the error telling you the file is not writable.

To fix it , you can simply update the file permission

```
cd <directory of name.txt>
chmod 777 name.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of that you are writing fwrite wrong.

You are doing:

```
fwrite($fh, $name, $surname);
```

You should do:

```
fwrite($fh, $name. ', '. $surname);
```

Function `fwrite()` excepts 2 parameters. You are giving 3.